# Captialized names and remove underscore from API drop down list appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am able to get API fields on the front end HTML field box dropdown successfully.

I want achieve Account Currency instead of account_currency on the front end. How can I acheive that.

Code.gs

```
var ACCOUNTDATA = {
    adAccountUIFields: ['account_currency', 'account_id', ...... ]

}
```

html

```
<select id="fieldsData">
  
<? var data = ACCOUNTDATA.adAccountUIFields ?>
 <? if (data.length > 0) { ?>
<? for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) { ?>
 <option value="<?= data[i] ?>"><?= data[i] ?></option>
   <? } ?>
 <? } ?>

   </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to separate the strings between `_`.
- Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [toUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) to capitalize the first letter in each word.
- Use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join the words back to a single string, with blank spaces in between.

```
const updatedData = data[i].split("_")
                           .map(word => word.replace(/./, i => i.toUpperCase()))
                           .join(" ");
```